# Telerik Kendo MVC Grid - Server Binding - Using the default event handler

Tags: c#, telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am creating a server bound Kendo grid and for the moment I would like to use the default error handler Telerik provides in their demo pages:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function error(args) {
        if (args.errors) {
            var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
            grid.one("dataBinding", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();   // cancel grid rebind if error occurs                                             
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

The grid works fine until I add `.Events(e => e.Error("error"))` to the data source section.  After I add this line and publish to my test server, I try loading the page and I receive a Compilation Error stating:

> CS1660: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type.

I have searched and found plenty of people mentioning this particular error related in relation to Kendo grids and many other things so it does not appear to be directly related to the Kendo product.  However I have been unable to determine what the error really means and why I am suddenly receiving it after trying to add error handling to my grid.

Just for curiosity's sake, I did try moving the .Error() line out of the data source and put it at the same level.  This produced the following error:

> CS1061: 'Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.GridEventBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'Error' and no extension method 'Error' accepting a first argument of type 'Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.GridEventBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

GRID CODE:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
.Name("grid")
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Server()
    .Events(e => e.Error("error"))
    .Filter(filter => filter.Add(f => f.Active).IsEqualTo(true))
    .Model(model => 
        {
            model.Id(q => q.ID);
            model.Field(q => q.Active).Editable(false);
            model.Field(q => q.CreateDate).Editable(false);
            model.Field(q => q.CreatedByUser).Editable(false);
            model.Field(q => q.LastChangeDate).Editable(false);
            model.Field(q => q.LastChangedByUser).Editable(false);
            model.Field(q => q.DeleteDate).Editable(false);
            model.Field(q => q.DeletedByUser).Editable(false);                            
        })
    .PageSize(MyProduct.Core.Settings.GetSettingValueInt(MyProduct.Core.Settings.SettingsID.TableMxPageSize, 100))
    .Sort(sort => { if (Request.QueryString.Keys.Count == 0) { sort.Add("HolidayDate").Ascending(); } }) // Initial Sort
    .Create(create => create.Action("NonTradeDays_Create", "CommodityPricing"))
    .Read(read => read.Action("NonTradeDays", "CommodityPricing"))
    .Update(update => update.Action("NonTradeDays_Update", "CommodityPricing"))
    .Destroy(update => update.Action("NonTradeDays_ActiveState", "CommodityPricing"))                    
)
.ToolBar(command =>
    {
        command.Create();
    })
.Editable(edit => edit.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp))                
.Pageable(pager => pager
    .PageSizes(new int[] { 50, 100, 250 })
    .Refresh(true)
)
.Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
.Filterable(ftb => { ftb.Mode(GridFilterMode.Menu); })
.Sortable()
.Groupable()
.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 800px;" })
.Scrollable()
.Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Command(q => { q.Edit(); q.Destroy(); })
            .Width(100);
        columns.Bound(q => q.Active)
            .Title("Active?")
            .Width(85);
        columns.Bound(q => q.HolidayDate)
            .Title("Date")
            .Width(200);
        columns.Bound(q => q.Name)
            .Template(@<text>
                @if (!User.IsInRole("manageNonTradeDays"))
                { <div class="noAdd"></div>}
                @if (!User.IsInRole("manageNonTradeDays"))
                { <div class="noEdit"></div>}
                @if (!User.IsInRole("manageNonTradeDays"))
                { <div class="noDeactivate"></div>}
                @if (item.DeleteDate != null)
                { <div class="isDeleted"></div>}
                @item.Name
                </text>)
            .Width(300);
        columns.Bound(q => q.CreateDate)
            .Width(200);
        columns.Bound(q => q.CreatedByUser)
            .Width(175);
        columns.Bound(q => q.LastChangeDate)
            .Width(200);
        columns.Bound(q => q.LastChangedByUser)
            .Width(200);
        columns.Bound(q => q.DeleteDate)
            .Width(200);
        columns.Bound(q => q.DeletedByUser)
            .Width(200);
    }
))
```

If I've not included enough information, please let me know what else you need to know.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: That event is not for a server-binding grid. For a server-binding grid, you can do the error handling in your Controller and redirect to an Error view, in case there's any exception.

Comment: @ataravati, thank you for the clarification.  I must have been looking at Ajax binding examples when I found that .Event() line in the grid data source.  Since this project was about trying to decide between the two binding options going forward, I will attempt to build my grid using Ajax binding and see how far I get.